# A step in a proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I just need a step in a proof by contradiction explained. It has to be proven that if a times b is even then at least one of them is also even.  This is done by proving that if a times b is odd, then both a and b are also odd.

Here are the steps of the proof:

```
a = 2m + 1 ∧ b = 2n + 1, where m, n ∈ Z ⇒
ab = (2m + 1)(2n + 1), where m, n ∈ Z ⇒
ab = 2(2mn + 2n + 1) + 1, where m, n ∈ Z ⇒
ab is odd
```

The step I'm having trouble understanding is this:

```
ab = (2m + 1)(2n + 1), where m, n ∈ Z ⇒
ab = 2(2mn + 2n + 1) + 1, where m, n ∈ Z
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (2m + 1)(2n + 1) = 4mn + 2m + 2n + 1 = 2(2mn + 2m + 2n) + 1

Comment: Foil out $(2m+1)(2n+1)$ and simplify to that form. I.e. do exactly what is done above this comment^

Comment: Still don't get it. Isn't 2(2mn+2m+2n)+1 = 4mn+4m+4n+1 ?

Comment: It sure looks like a typo to me.  Kind of a weird one but $(2m + 1)(2n + 1) = 4mn + 2m + 2n + 1 = 2(2mn + 2m + 2n) + 1 \ne 2(2mn + 2n + 1) + 1$ unless n = m -1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a typo.

I'd do it:

$ab = (2m + 1)(2n + 1) = 4mn + 2n + 2m + 1 = 2(2mn + n + m) + 1$

It looks like the typer mistyped "1" for "m".

That's all.  It's sill an odd number.

Comment: Well, it makes sense to me if that is the case. Hope you're right, thanks!

Comment: I don't know.  It *looks* like a typo.  If (2m + 1)(2n + 1) = 2(2mn + m + n) + 1 = 2(2mn + 2n + 1) + 1 then n = m -1.  Was anything like that ever stated?  I doubt it.